# Does “with” and “whose” have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning

> Company whose shares have just increased was sold.

> Company with shares having just increased was sold.

Does both sentence have the same meaning or the second one means differently? I mean Can I use with instead of whose?

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. 3. No.

Comment: If you would like a longer more detailed answer, please explain why you think "with" is interchangeable with "whose".

Comment: I just wonder can I use with in this way?

Comment: The first example is much better, and easier to parse. Although probably fine as a title for an article. I'd add a determiner (a/the): **A company whose shares** have....

Comment: Is the second one tottally wrong or odd?

Comment: "A man with a car was stolen…" doesn't necessarily mean he is the owner of the car, it could be the car of someone else or it could belong to the company he works for. **What was stolen, the man or the car?** It's ambiguous. "*A man whose car was stolen* ...” This tells us the car that was stolen belonged to the man. "*A man whose company car was stolen* …" this tells us that car belonged to the company. Your 2nd sentence is ambiguous but if the context is clear it would make sense. It just sounds like bad writing.

Comment: Got it. It is grammatical but not as clear as first one.

Comment: 'A company with shares' is not at all idiomatic. It's normal for a limited company to issue shares. We wouldn't say 'A man with legs that were injured'.